# How do I prompt a user until they enter a valid integer?

Tags: java, integer, java.util.scanner

Valid integer being a letter. I don't know the command to make it check the strings, nor do I know where to find it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stringtest{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int test = 10;

    while (test>0){
    System.out.println("Input the maximum temperature.");
    String maxTemp = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input the minimum temperature.");
    String minTemp = input.nextLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html, and with the [`Scanner` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Just use `input.nextInt()`, and then a simple `try-catch` for an invalid int. You shouldn't try to save temperature indexes as `Strings` either.

Comment: input.nextInt only accepts integers? Wow. I'm such a noobie, thanks xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) to get the next integer value. 
You should try/catch it in case user types a non-integer value.

Here's an example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// infinite loop
while (true){
        System.out.println("Input the maximum temperature.");
        try {
            int maxTemp = input.nextInt();
            // TODO whatever you need to do with max temp
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            // TODO handle better
            t.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Input the minimum temperature.");
        try {
            int minTemp = input.nextInt();
            // TODO whatever you need to do with min temp
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            // TODO handle better
            t.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Mena, check the OP's latest questions. Looks like you're not teaching him to learn Java but rather are teaching him to beg for code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels feeling a bit guilty now ;( Still, there are instruments to regulate/moderate the community...

Answer (score 1):

Just use `input.nextInt()`, and then a simple try-catch for an invalid int value.

You shouldn't try to save temperature indexes as `Strings` either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Integer.parseInt` i.e User can enter any String and then you can check if it is an integer using this api, if it is not integer you will get an exception and then you can for another entry from user. Check below link for usage.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
 int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
 // is an integer!
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
 // not an integer!
 }
```

Comment: It's better to use `Scanner#hasNextInt()` and `Scanner#nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number: ");
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        String input = scanner.next();
        System.out.printf("\"%s\" is not a valid number.\n", input);
    }
    number = scanner.nextInt();
} while (number < 0);
```